# Find out the coordinates using slope and start point

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am trying to achieve a task which is to resize the line after taking length input from user.So what I have currently is old length,old points(P1 ,P2) and have to find the new P2 after taking new length from user.I am here pasting code which I have tried to resize line using slope but its not working.I am totally new in canvas part to any kind of search hint will also be appreciable.Thanks in advance.

**Method to find out the angle between previous points**:

```
public double calculateAngle(){
  if(selectedShape!=null){      
  InnWall shape  = (InnWall)selectedShape;
    if(shape!=null)
    return calAngle(shape.y2-shape.y1, shape.x2-shape.x1);
  }
return -1;
}
```

**Method to find out he coordinates**

```
public void calCoordinates(double length){

        InnWall shape  = (InnWall)selectedShape;
        if(shape!=null){
            double angle = calculateAngle();
        Log.e(TAG, "cal angle"+(int)calculateAngle());
        Log.e(TAG, "cal length"+(int)length);
        Log.e(TAG, "x coodinatee"+shape.x1+length*Math.cos(angle));
        Log.e(TAG, "y coodinatee"+shape.y1+length*Math.sin(angle));
        shape.x2=(float)(shape.x1+length*Math.cos(angle));
        shape.y2=(float)(shape.y1+length*Math.sin(angle));

}

private  double calAngle(double dy,double dx){
        return double compassBearing=dy/dx;
}
```

Comment: Where's `calAngle()`?

Comment: Btw, you don't need trigonometry at all. dx & dy scale linearily with the length of the line.

Comment: @HannoBinder please see eddited one

Comment: `calAngle()` does not make any sense this way. It's not even syntactically valid. Is there some code missing from it?

Comment: Pseudocode: `len_old = Math.sqrt( dx*dx+dy*dy ); scale_factor = length / len_old; p2_new = p1 + (p2_old-p1) * scale_factor;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double scale = old_length/new_length;
dx = p2.x - p1.x
dy = p2.y - p1.y
```

You know that:

```
 - scale_x^2 + scale_y^2 = scale^2
 - scale_x/scale_y = dx/dy
```

Thus:

```
scale_y = sqrt(scale * scale * dy *dy/(dx*dx + dy*dy));
scale_x = scale_y*dx/dy;
```

If the relative point is P1
Then 
p2.x += (p2.x-p1.x) * scale_x
p2.y += (p2.y-p1.y) * scale_y

In theory, for scaling you need to multiply the points with a scaling matrix which in your case is 2D.

```
[ 1  0  dx ] [ p1.x ]    [ p2.x ]
[ 0  1  dy ] [ p1.y ]  = [ p2.y ]
[ 0  0  1  ] [ 1    ]    [ 1  ]
```

Comment: Hi Cosmin , first of all thanks a ton for the solution.Just one doubt ,should length be in pixels?

Comment: Also doesn't it related to direction( angle ) of line where has to extend?As in my case it is not working properly

Comment: It is working fine when line is vertical/horizontal.But dont work when line is at any angle.

Comment: The length is converted in pixels only at the end of the computations. Before computation you need to take care that all the variables are float or double because int and double/float have different / meaning. For floats and doubles it means floating point division, but for int / means the integer part of the division. For 2, 3 as integers, 2/3 = 0, meanwhile for 2 and 3 as floats, 2/3 = 0,666...